# asp.net 4.6.1 can't create log file using NLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I'm trying to log some application info using `NLog 4.4.12` But I can't seem to create the log file in my `C drive`.

I have a class library running on `.net 4.6.1`

I have created an `NLog.config` in the root directory of that project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\ApiLogfile.txt" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

When I call `logger.Info("NLog to the rescue")` the output file isn't created in the C drive. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the nlog.config in the bin or root folder of your starting application?

Comment: Also it could be an permission error. You could try c:/temp or check the internal log. Check https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: @Julian The Nlog.config is in the class library not the starting application. Should I move it over? Also I will check the permissions and let you know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes it should be in the start-up application, or you should add some code (well 1 line), to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get it to work using

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\ApiLogfile.txt" />
```

This is probably a permissions issue and if you execute the application as Administrator it does work.

These two locations worked for me:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/ApiLogfile.txt" />
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Users\{username}\Documents\ApiLogfile.txt" />
```

Also ensure the **Copy to Output Directory** is set to **Copy always** for the NLog.config file to ensure it is copied to the output directory, which is where NLog assembly expects it to be.